# Select random number within a specific range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, random

I'd like to select a random decimal between, say, .40 and .60. So .45 or .55 would be desired. .61 not. All ranges would be between 0 and 1.

I have googled and seem to be able to do this with integers using `rand()*` but can't seem to get it quite right for decimals only.

Comment: Do you want one random number or one random number per row in a table?

Comment: Ultimately, one random number per row in a table, but I know how to do that already.

Answer (score 2):

The general form of generating a random number would be `min + rand() * (max - min)`. So, in your case:

```sql
SELECT 0.4 + RAND() * 0.2
```